# ios AUGraph pitch shifting in ios 5.0

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I was reading through the documentation on the AUGraph and came across a nice addition in ios 5.0

kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch has been added.

Goal: To be able to change the pitch and playback rate of my inputs without reinitializing the AUgraph or any other objects.

Does anyone have a good tutorial on the usage of AUConverters or could point me to a good example? I've watched the wwdc videos and none talked about AUConverters.

Answer (score 2):

kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch isnt actually available on ios5. There's an audio unit you can use named kAudioUnitSubType_VariSpeed. With this component if you change the pitch the rate changes and visa versa. You can't change pitch and rate seperatley with this.